# Custom directories names in Vue + ASP.NET Core Web API

Tags: asp.net-core, vuejs3

Help me please to configure my vue app. I want to use Vue over ASP.NET Core Web API.

This is what I have done:

Startup.cs

```
public void ConfigureServices(IServiceCollection services)
{
    services.AddControllers();
    services.AddSpaStaticFiles(options => options.RootPath = "Client/Dist");
}

public void Configure(IApplicationBuilder app, IWebHostEnvironment env)
{
    app.UseRouting();

    app.UseEndpoints(endpoints =>
    {
        endpoints.MapControllerRoute(
            name: "api",
            pattern: "api/{controller}/{action}/{id?}");
    });

    app.UseSpaStaticFiles();
    app.UseSpa(x => { x.Options.SourcePath="Client/Dist"; });
}
```

Then I created vue app with vue-cli. I chose configs built in package json. And then I renamed directories:

[image]

And I put these lines into package.json

```
"vue": {
  "pages": {
    "index": {
      "entry": "Sources/Index.ts",
       "template": "Public/Index.html",
       "filename": "index.html"
      }
    },
  "outputDir": "Dist"
}
```

The build process was successful, but

1. `Favicon.ico` was not copied to the `Dist` folder after build
2. In the browser there is only white screen. There are no any errors in the console, all requests are successful. Vue just doesn't add anything to the root node (`<div id ="app">`)

I think, that the problem is in my custom filenames and I don't know what I should add into config to fix that

Comment: Can you tell us which file name you have changed? Whether you are using webpack or not? Any static assets placed in the public folder will simply be copied and not go through webpack. You need to reference them using absolute paths. If you change the file name, you might have to change the `.csproj` file. Besides, when you configure the Spa service in the Configure method, set the source path as below: `app.UseSpa(x => { x.Options.SourcePath="Client"; });`.

Comment: @ZhiLv 
- `{ x.Options.SourcePath="Client/Dist"; }` should stay as is, because it's looking for `Client/Dist/index.html` (it is placed there).

As I understand, vue-cli uses webpack somewhere inside, but I don't use it expicitly. I only use  configuration in package.json ("vue" field). I capitalised directories' names, rename src folder -> Sources, and main.ts -> Index.ts. My Favicon.ico file placed in Public folder, but it's not copied into Dist folder after build